# VSCode unhide sys.platform Python code for cross platform dev

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm working on a Python project using Pylance that involves checking `if sys.platform == "win32":` and `elif sys.platform == "darwin":`
Working on a Windows machine makes all the code inside the `elif sys.platform == "darwin":` greyed out (code is unreachable) which I understand. But it also means that menu options like `Rename Symbol` and `Find all References` don't alter or find parts in that section of code... I don't want this, I want all the code to be evaluated / visible to VSCode menu commands for cross platform development... is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's provided by the Language Server of `Pylance`. And it has not available methods to disable it for now. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/248) for more details.

My suggestion is, change the code of `if sys.platform == "win32":` to something others, such as if `sys.platform == "win322":` temporarily. Or you can have a try on some other Language Serve, such as: `JediLSP`.